# Why the sad text is positive?

Tags: r, string, numbers

I have a string and while comparing with number it does not break and say that this is positive, any hints why this happens?

```
x <- "The day is bad, I don't like anything! I feel bad and sad really sad"
if (x == 0) {
   print("x is equal to 0")
}else if (x > 0) {
   print("x is positive")
}else if (x < 0 ){
   print("x is negative")
}
```

The result is:

```
"x is positive"
```

Comment: You have a string 'x', then you are doing the comparison with `x == 0` Have you missed any code

Comment: It could be a result of the ASCII code where the values would be greater than number 0.  For e.g. `letters > 0`

Comment: The ideia is to see if the code would eventually break. It is a bit confusing and I see potential problems where this comparisons should't occur.

Answer (score 8):

```
?'>'
```

> ...If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being **character**, complex, **numeric**, integer, logical and raw...

So while you compare `x` which is *character* vector, to `0`, that is *numeric* type, former is converted to character `'0'`:

- `x == 0` evaluates to `FALSE` because `"The day is bad..." != "0"`;
- `x <  0` evaluates to `FALSE` because while ordered, `0` is placed *before* `"The day is bad..."` :

> ...Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within
>   the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use...

```
sort(c(x, 0))
#[1] "0"                                                                   
#[2] "The day is bad, I don't like anything! I feel bad and sad really sad"
```

Meaning that `x` is thought as *greater* than `'0'` because of the lexicographic order.

- Finally `x > 0` evaluates to `TRUE` because `'0'` precedes `'The day is bad, I dont...'` and  your code returns `[1] x is positive`

And if, trying to prove our hypothesis, we ask ourselves, whether Chuck Norris is able to beat the Infinity, we find that it is not the case:

```
'Chuck Norris' > Inf
# [1] FALSE
```

In contrast, Keith Richards, as anybody would expect, have no problem with that:

```
'Keith Richards' > Inf
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Laughing out loud with that final part :0 Great examples! Thanks for the detailed answer!